# laravel 4 where the beforefilter's second parameter pass to?

Tags: laravel-4

I find this example from documentation:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

        /**
         * Instantiate a new UserController instance.
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
        $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => 'getLogin'));

        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));

        $this->afterFilter('log', array('only' =>
                        array('fooAction', 'barAction')));
        }

    }
```

I am confused,because I checked the filters.php,
and find that,the auth filter dosen't have any identifiers:

```
    Route::filter('auth', function()
{
   if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});
```

I wonder know where the beforefilter's second parameter pass to? 
Can somebody help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong place. That `array` parameter is not being passed to the `auth` filter. It's a parameter for `Controller.beforeFilter()`.

As you can see in [Laravel's documentation](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Routing.Controllers.Controller.html#9-305), `beforeFilter()` expects two parameters:

1. `$filter` The filter to be executed **before** your controller actions. These filters are the ones that you see in `filters.php` file.
2. `$options` An array with options for the filter being passed. In this case, you are passing the `except` option with a value of `getLogin`.

---

```
/**
* Register a new "before" filter on the controller.
*
* @param  string  $filter
* @param  array   $options
* @return void
*/
public function beforeFilter($filter, array $options = array())
{
    $options = $this->prepareFilter($filter, $options);

    $this->filters[] = new Before($options);
}
```

Comment: Hi Manuel, could you please tell me what are the options other than "except" ? I tried to find in the docs but could not find any detail. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: @AbhayPS sure, take a look here: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#controller-filters

Comment: Thanks Manuel, it was a great help. I have been looking for it for quite a while.